# Hibernate entity with enum foreign key

Tags: oracle, hibernate, enums, mapping

I'm not sure if the topic name makes sense. 
Anyway, the problem is that in my table I have column which stores fk to dictionary table and I want to map it in hibernate in a way that getType will return a value from this dictionary. As an example I have row with type id = 1 which in dictionary corresponds to HIGH, and I have such enum declared in java as ProductType, I want to have method 
ProductType getType() which will automatically map values from column type to my enum.

If something's not clear, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to mark an Enum as Entity's property/column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to my question

```
@Column(name="TYPE_ID") 
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) 
private MyType myType;
```

Of course my enum looks as follows:

```
public enum MyType {

HIGH(1),
LOW(2);
```